# If $f_{n}$ are non-negative and $\int_{X}f_{n}d\mu=1$ does $\frac{1}{n}f_{n}$ converge almost-everywhere to $0$? does $\frac{1}{n^{2}}f_{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Question from an exam sample I'm studying for:** Suppose $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
  is a measure space and $f_{n}:\left(X,\mathcal{F}\right)\to\mathbb{R}$
  a sequence of non-negative integrable functions such that $\int_{X}f_{n}d\mu=1$
 . Is is it necessarily true that $\frac{1}{n}f_{n}$
  converges almost everywhere to $0$
 ? what about $\frac{1}{n^{2}}f_{n}$
 ?

**My line of thought:** From Fatou's llema we got that: $$\int\limits _{X}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}f_{n}d\mu\geq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int\limits _{X}\frac{1}{n}f_{n}d\mu=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int\limits _{X}f_{n}d\mu=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$
 Thus $g:=\liminf\frac{1}{n}f_{n}$
  is a non-negative function whose integral equals zero and thus $g=0$
  almost-everywhere. So if I knew that $\frac{1}{n}f_{n}$
  converged almost-everywhere then in particular it would be equal to $g$
  almost-everywhere and thus to $0$
 . I've been racking my head trying to think whether it's possible to construct a sequence with the given properties such that $\frac{1}{n}f_{n}$
  would fail to converge on a set of positive measure. I want to say that this is impossible and that both claims are true (which would make the phrasing of the question quite mean since these questions usually imply one case is true and one is false) but I'm not certain.

I'd really appreciate help clearing this up!

**Edit:** Since you can only accept one answer I wanted to thank Did, Vincent and M. Luethi for their replies. Combined we got two counter-examples for $\frac{1}{n}$ and a proof for $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typewriter sequence disproves the almost sure convergence of $\frac1nf_n$ (see Example 4 [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/)). To study $\frac1{n^2}f_n$, generalize slightly the setting and consider the function $g=\sum\limits_na_nf_n$ where $\sum\limits_na_n$ is a series with positive entries and finite sum. Henri Lebesgue taught us that $$\int g=\sum_na_n\int f_n=\sum_na_n$$ is finite hence $g$ is finite almost everywhere, in particular $a_nf_n\to0$ almost everywhere. This applies to $a_n=\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: Wow. That is a really really nice proof.

Comment: So in general we have that if $\int f_{n} = 1$ and we have a sequence $a_{n} f_{n}$ such that $\sum a_{n}$ is convergent, then $a_{n} f_{n}$ converges a.e. to zero and if $\sum a_{n}$ is divergent then it does not converge to zero a.e. in general.

Comment: @Vincent If $\sum a_n$ converges then $a_nf_n\to0$ almost everywhere. If $\sum a_n$ diverges then of course everything can happen.

Comment: I tried to summarize it, but 'anything can happen' means that we can always find a counterexample such that $a_{n} f_{n}$ does not converge to zero almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I make it an answer but I leave out a few details so that you still have to look at it a bit. I can add the details later if need be.

Look at the unit interval $[0,1]$ and define a collection of natural coverings: $$\begin{align}P_{k}=\left\{\left[0,\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right],\ldots,\left[\frac{2^{k}-1}{2^{k}},1\right]\right\}\end{align}$$ Define the sequence $f_{n}$ by choosing $k$ such that $2^{k}\leq n < 2^{k+1}$ and let $f_{n}:=2^{k}1_{\left[\frac{n-2^{k}}{2^{k}},\frac{n+1-2^{k}}{2^{k}}\right]}$.

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\frac{1}{n}f_{n}(x)=\frac{2^{k}}{n}$ where $2^{k}\leq n\leq 2^{k+1}$, so that $\frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{2^{k}}{n}\leq 1$. In order to see that every $x\in[0,1]$ lands in infinitely many of the intervals, it suffices to check that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $0\leq l<2^{k}$, there exists a natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n=2^{k}+l$, because then all $P_{k}$ appear in our sequence. But the existence of $n$ is obvious.

Comment: This type of sequence is known as the _typewriter sequence_.

Comment: @Serpahimz I haven't checked letter by letter the answer of M.Luethi, but this type of construction in measure theory is standard, so it is worth to understand well.

Comment: I made a mistake initially, that's why so many questions popped up. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Define the sets $A_{n}$ as following:
$$
 A_{n} = \{ x \in [0,1] \, : \, \mbox{x - y is an integer with} \, \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} \leq y \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\}.
$$
Then $\mu(A_{n}) = \frac{1}{n}$. Now define $f_{n}(x) = n \cdot \chi_{A_{n}}$ with $\chi_{A_{n}}$ the indicator function on $A_{n}$. Then $\int_{X} f_{n} d\mu = 1$ follows. Can you prove that $\frac{1}{n} f_{n}(x)$ converges nowhere on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Note that for my purpose I need that $\frac{1}{n}f_{n}$ would not converge anywhere and not $f_{n}$ itself.

Comment: That's what I meant, I will fix it.

Comment: I get the idea of the construction. I'm not sure I understand how to definition of $f_{n}$ works out though. Wouldn't it also suffice to define the functions to be $n$ on $A_{n}$ instead?

Comment: No, in that case, since $\sum \frac{1}{k} \to \infty$, one could say that for any point $x \in R$, there exists a $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} > x$. Hence $f_{n}(x) = 0$ for all $n \geq N$ and it would converge to zero. Therefore we need that we remain in the same interval, but since $\sum \frac{1}{k} \to \infty$, every point $x \in [0,1]$ would be in infinitely many intervals $A_{n}$ 'modulo $Z$' (the integers).

Comment: I will edit my solution a bit further...

Comment: This doesn't really work for $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ though or am I missing something?. You'd want to increase the value of the function to be $n^{2}$ on a set of measure $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$  and I don't see how to do that in your construction.