# Measure Theory - Series of functions

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

A question from my homework I wasn't sure about:

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of integrable non-negative functions on a measure space $(X,F,\mu)$ s.t. $\int_Xf_n(x)\,d\mu=1$.
>
> Is one of the following necessarily true? $\frac{1}{n}f_n \to 0$ a.e. or  $\frac{1}{n^2}f_n \to 0$ a.e. as $n \to \infty$.

I think the answer to both of them is no, but I find it odd that the question would be phrased like this if that's indeed the case, so I want to make sure I'm not making a mistake:

Construct the following sequence of functions on the real line w.r.t. to Lebesgue measure:

Let $A_n$ be a binary partition of $[0,1]$, i.e. $A_1=[0,\frac{1}{2})$,  $A_2=[\frac{1}{2},1)$ , $A_3=[0,\frac{1}{4})$ etc.

Set: $f_n = 2^n$ for $x\in A_n$ and zero otherwise. (Edit: I mean here that $f_n = 2^k$ where k is the relevant power for n. Sorry for not being more formal).

$f_n$ matches the criteria of the question but doesn't go to zero on $[0,1]$ when divided by $n^k$ for any k. Is this correct?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your reasoning seems sound to me. Edit: oh, I'd add the [tag:proof-verification] tag.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662283/if-f-n-are-non-negative-and-int-xf-nd-mu-1-does-frac1nf-n-co).

Comment: Thank you David! That is the same question indeed, but I'm not sure I understand the reasoning given by Did there. It is a consequence of monotone convergence? Why does my example fail for $n^2$?

Thank you!

Comment: For instance, considering dividing by $n^2$,  $f_{2^2+3}$ would be divided by $(2^2+3)^2$, but $f_{2^2+3}$ corresponds to the interval $[3/4,1]$ and takes value $2^2$ there. $f_{2^3+7}$ has non-zero value of $2^3$ and would be divided by $(2^3+7)^2$.  (I hope this makes sense.)

Comment: In the above, I started with $f_1$ to be the identically $1$ function; so my $f_2$ is your $f_1$.

Comment: Ok you're right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In general, on the $n$'th "dyadic level",  $f_{2^n+k}$ has non-zero value $2^n$, and $0\le f_{2^n+k}/(2^n+k)^2 \le 1/2^n$.